# Subscribe to paginated list

Tags: pagination, deepstream.io

I'm searching for a framework capable of subscribing to live updates on a paginated list.

The server should take into account the users query for that subscription, and should only send the updates to the subscribers that passes the query instead of broadcasting to everyone.

Is this possible to implement in deepstream.io, and how hard and efficient is it?

I've been using Meteor for this, but I'm trying to deviate from this stack.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using deepstream in conjunction with RethinkDb should do the trick. Have a look at the official RethinkDb search provider (https://github.com/hoxton-one/deepstream.io-provider-search-rethinkdb) which already creates dynamic lists based on queries. Adding pagination to it should be reasonably straight forward.